# What's the difference between this.$data.randomData & this.randomData

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

What is the difference between `this.$data.randomData` and `this.randomData` when accessing data in a component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`vm.$data` is the actual data object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data). The thing is the Vue instance proxies access to `$data`, meaning (almost, see below) anything like `this.$data.bob` will be accessible as `this.bob`. [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> After the instance is created, the original data object can be
> accessed as `vm.$data`. The Vue instance also proxies all the
> properties found on the data object, so `vm.a` will be equivalent to
> `vm.$data.a`.

What is `$data` good for, then?
As far as I can tell, there are two possible cases that only `$data` can help you:

- If you have properties starting with `_` or `$` they are not proxied.

  - So if you have `data._bob` it won't be available as `this._bob`, just as `this.$data.bob`.
  - [Relevant docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

    > Properties that start with `_` or `$` will **not** be proxied on the
    > Vue instance because they may conflict with Vue's internal properties
    > and API methods. You will have to access them as `vm.$data._property`.
- If you want the whole `data` object's content.

  - [Relevant docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

    > If required, a deep clone of the original object can be obtained by
    > passing `vm.$data` through `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`.

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    $alice: 'Alice',
    _bob: 'Bob'
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Whole data is:', this.$data)
    console.log('this.$alice is:', this.$alice)
    console.log('this.$data.$alice is:', this.$data.$alice)
    console.log('this._bob is:', this._bob)
    console.log('this.$data._bob is:', this.$data._bob)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Whole object: {{ $data }}</p>
  <p>$data.$alice: {{ $data.$alice }}</p>
  <p>$data._bob: {{ $data._bob }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you get to try it out?